# Searching for words in one file from another file

Tags: windows, search, sed, dos

I am looking for a way to search words in one file (about 16000) by matching them with words from another file (about 1000000 words).  The catch is I am on windows command line.  I downloaded sed but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Download `grep` instead:

```
grep -Ff FILE_WITH_WORDS_TO_FIND FILE_WITH_WORDS
```